# Streaming an octet stream from request to S3 with knox on node.js

Tags: file-upload, stream, amazon-s3, node.js

I'm trying to stream an octet-stream straight to S3 using [knox](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox/) on node.js. The octet-stream is an XHR file upload from the browser. I assumed that I could just stream the request into putStream and everything would just work, but alas no.

Here's my code:

```
var client = knox.createClient({ 
           // AWS credentials here
         });
if (req.headers['content-type'].match(/application\/octet-stream/i)) {

  var filename = '/'+req.headers['x-file-name'];

  client.putStream(req, filename, function(err, res){
    // TODO: Catch errors
    body = '{"success":"true"}'
    res.writeHead(200, 
      { 'Content-Type':'text/html'
      , 'Content-Length':body.length
      })
    res.end(body)
  });

}
```

And the error I receive:

```
TypeError: Bad argument
    at Object.stat (fs.js:354:11)
    at Client.putStream (./lib/knox/client.js:181:6)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing something like this:

```
app.post('/uploadAmazon', function(req, res) {  
var params = req.query;

var request = client.request("PUT", '/' + req.header('x-file-name') + '?partNumber=' + params.partNumber 
        + '&uploadId=' + params.uploadId, {
    'Content-Length' : req.header('Content-Length')
} );

req.on('data', function(data){
    request.write(data);
});


request.on('response', function(response) {
    console.log('Partial ' + params.partNumber + ' statusCode: ' + response.statusCode);
    if (response.statusCode== 200) {
        uploadMap[params.id].currentSize++;
        uploadMap[params.id].completeXmlArray[+(params.partNumber) - 1] = '<Part><PartNumber>' + params.partNumber + '</PartNumber><ETag>' + response.headers.etag + '</ETag></Part>' ; 

        if (uploadMap[params.id].currentSize == uploadMap[params.id].totalSize) {
            uploadMap[params.id].uploadId = params.uploadId;
            completeSend(uploadMap[params.id]);
        }
    }
}).end();

res.end();
```

});

Assuming that I receive the file name, part number and uploadId from the post.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `client.putStream` accepts 4 params, like this:

```
client.putStream(stream, filepath, {
  'Content-Length': file.length,
  'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
  'x-amz-acl': 'private'
}, function(err, res) {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version of node.js much older than 0.4.5 then upgrade.

Look in the [util module](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.5/api/util.html) and use util.pump to copy the file from the input stream to the output stream. If the file has to be downloaded first, just use a ReadStream from the file as the input stream.

Also, do have a look at the [Javascript code for util.pump](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/util.js) because I suspect that you haven't quite grasped how async I/O works in node.js.