# Accessing the raw file stream from a node-formidable file upload

Tags: node.js, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am creating an application that takes some file uploads and send them straight up to S3.  I would prefer not to even have the tmp file on my server, so I am using the Knox module and would like to take the raw stream from Formidable and send it over Knox to S3.  I have done something similar using Knox to download a file using this code:

```
knox.downloads.get(widget.download).on('response',function(sres){
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type':'application/zip',
        'Content-Length': sres.headers['content-length'],
        'Content-Disposition':'attachment; filename=' + widget.download
    });
    util.pump(sres, res);
}).end();
```

Now I would like to do something similar in the oposite direction (File upload from the browser to S3).

So far I have written an event handler to capture each piece of data from the file as it's being uploaded:

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.onPart = function(part){
    if(!part.filename){
        form.handlePart(part);
    }else{
        if(part.name == 'download'){
            // Upload to download bucket
            controller.putDownload(part);
        }else{
            // Upload to the image bucket
            controller.putImage(part);
        }
        //res.send(sys.inspect(part));
    }
}
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
    if(err){
        res.json(err);
    }else{
        res.send(sys.inspect({fields:fields, files:files}), {'content-type':'text/plain'});
        //controller.createWidget(res,fields,files);            
    }
});


controller.putDownload = function(part){
    part.addListener('data', function(buffer){
        knox.download.putStream(data,part.filename, function(err,s3res){
            if(err)throwError(err);
            else{
                console.log(s3res);
            }
        });
    })
    knox.downloads.putStream(part, part.filename, function(err,s3res){

        if(err)throwError(err);
        else{
            console.log(s3res);
        }
    });
}
```

But the data event only give me the buffer.  So is it possible to capture the stream itself and push it to S3?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you want to do is override the `Form.onPart` method:

```
IncomingForm.prototype.onPart = function(part) {
  // this method can be overwritten by the user
  this.handlePart(part);
};
```

Formidable's default behavior is to write the part to a file. You don't want that. You want to handle the 'part' events to write to the knox download. Start with this:

```
form.onPart = function(part) {
    if (!part.filename) {
        // let formidable handle all non-file parts
        form.handlePart(part);
        return;
    }
```

Then open the knox request and handle the raw part events yourself:

```
part.on('data', function(data) {
    req.write(data);
});
part.on('end', function() {
    req.end();
});
part.on('error', function(err) {
    // handle this too
});
```

As a bonus, if the `req.write(data)` return false that means the send buffer is full. You should pause the Formidable parser. When you get a `drain` event from the Knox stream you should resume Formidable.

Answer (score 7):

Use [multiparty](https://github.com/superjoe30/node-multiparty) instead. It supports this kind of streaming like you want. It even has an example of streaming directly to s3: https://github.com/superjoe30/node-multiparty/blob/master/examples/s3.js

Comment: i was so stuck and switching to multiparty solved this

Answer (score 4):

In an Express middleware, I use `formidable` together with `PassThrough` to stream-upload a file to S3 (in my case, to Minio which is S3 compatible through Minio SDK; and I believe it works for AWS S3 too with the same Minio SDK)

Here is the sample code.

```
const formidable = require('formidable')
const { PassThrough } = require('stream')

const form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
const pass = new PassThrough()

const fileMeta = {}
form.onPart = part => {
  if (!part.filename) {
    form.handlePart(part)
    return
  }
  fileMeta.name = part.filename
  fileMeta.type = part.mime
  part.on('data', function (buffer) {
    pass.write(buffer)
  })
  part.on('end', function () {
    pass.end()
  })
}
form.parse(req, err => {
  if (err) {
    req.minio = { error: err }
    next()
  } else {
    handlePostStream(req, next, fileMeta, pass)
  }
})
```

And `handlePostStream` looks like below, for your reference:

```
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1')

const handlePostStream = async (req, next, fileMeta, fileStream) => {
  let filename = uuidv1()

  try {
    const metaData = {
      'content-type': fileMeta.type,
      'file-name': Buffer.from(fileMeta.name).toString('base64')
    }

    const minioClient = /* Get Minio Client*/
    await minioClient.putObject(MINIO_BUCKET, filename, fileStream, metaData)

    req.minio = { post: { filename: `${filename}` } }
  } catch (error) {
    req.minio = { error }
  }
  next()
}
```

You can find [the source code on GitHub](https://github.com/yucigou/express-middleware-minio/blob/dev/src/index.js), and [its unit tests](https://github.com/yucigou/express-middleware-minio/blob/dev/src/__tests__/index.test.js) too.

Comment: this is not streaming directly to minio, it receives the stream first, then upload the local file to the server

Answer (score -1):

There is no way for you to capture the stream, because the data has to be translated by Formidable. The `buffer` you're given is the file contents in chunks of `buffer.length`: this might be a problem because looking at Formidable's docs it appears that until the file is completely uploaded it can't reliably report the file size and Knox's `put` method might need that.

Never used Knox this way before, but you might have some luck with something like this:

```
controller.putDownload = function(part){
    var req = knox.download.put(part.filename, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    part.addListener('data', function(buffer){
    req.write(buffer);
    });
    req.on('response', function(res){
       // error checking
    });
    req.end();
}
```

A little unsure about the response checking bits, but....see if you can whip that into shape. Also, [Streaming an octet stream from request to S3 with knox on node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052165/streaming-an-octet-stream-from-request-to-s3-with-knox-on-node-js) also has a writeup that may be useful to you.